# Prove that the roots of the equation $(a+b)x^2-(a+b+c)x+\frac{c}{2}=0$ are always real.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that the roots of the equation $(a+b)x^2-(a+b+c)x+\frac{c}{2}=0$ are always real.

For only real roots, $\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \geq 0$

Hence:

$\sqrt{[-(a+b+c)]^2-4(a+b)(\frac{c}{2})} \Rightarrow \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ac-2ac-2bc}$

$\Rightarrow \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab}$

$a^2+b^2+c^2>0$ is proven due to the squaring of each term. I know *intuitively* $a^2+b^2+c^2 > 2ab$ because squaring a quantity is usually larger than multiplying, but this isn't a definitive proof. I do not know what value $2ab$ is, since it could be negative.

Comment: *Hint*: Does $a^2+b^2+2ab$ remind you of anything?  Also don't forget to deal with special cases.

Comment: Aha $\sqrt{(a+b)^2+c^2} \geq 0$! Thanks. And what kinds of special cases?

Comment: What if it isn't really a quadratic, i.e., when $a=-b$?

Comment: Then the problem wouldn't exist :D

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson Of course if $a=b=c=0$ then any $x$ is a solution, e.g. $x=i,$ which is not real...

Comment: a²+b²+c²+2ab = (a+b)²+c²

Comment: Hint: AG inequality.